# Upgrading SSD in 2015 MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade, big-sur

I haven't been able to find the solution to my issue anywhere, so here goes:

I have a 15" MacBook Pro (mid 2015) and it's at all points a great device, with the only drawback being low storage (I only have the 256GB installed).

I am aware of OWC's solution and I almost bought a 2TB SSD, but then I remembered that the new macOS runs a bit differently, if I understand this right. I am not sure if the OWC's SSD would be even compatible with Big Sur (I also read somewhere that it's also completely incompatible with Windows 10 already, so no workarounds there?).

So, does anyone know how things stand right now with upgrading storage in "older" MacBook Pros in 2021?

Comment: Why do you think an OWC SSD would not be compatible with Big Sur? Given OWC's "30-Day Money Back 100% Guarantee," this looks like a very low-risk proposition.

Comment: What is your MBP's **Model Identifier**? You can see it at Apple Menu > About this Mac > Hardware > Hardware Overview > Model Identifier.

Comment: Hi, it is MacBookPro11,4.

I am aware the site says that it should be able to work, I was just wondering if it still does, since the SSD in question was released few years ago and Apple has made some pretty big changes since (on the software side at least).

Comment: I have a mid 2014 MacBook Pro that I upgraded with OWC's 2TB Aura Pro X2. Runs great with the new drive. (Unrelated to the drive, but macOS Big Sur frustrated me so much that I went back to macOS Catalina.) As for installing Windows, are you confusing Apple Silicon with Big Sur? Macs with Intel processors (like yours) can run Windows regardless of the operating system, but Macs with Apple processors can not.

Comment: I’ve edited your question by using  this article to identify the marketing name. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201300 You will certainly find an OWC that works with Big Sur - great machine indeed. +1 for asking

Answer (score 2):

[At least one of OWC's 2 TB SSD is compatible with OS 10.13 and later](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/S3DAPT4MB20K/). From the page for the OWC Aura Pro X2 SSD for the 2013-2015 Retina MBP:

"Aura Pro X2 is designed for the latest macOS versions (macOS High Sierra 10.13 and later), taking full advantage of the advanced features of APFS including: strong encryption, copy-on-write metadata, space sharing, cloning for files and directories, snapshots, fast directory sizing, atomic safe-save primitives, and improved file system fundamentals."